Show that no positive integer ending in $133$ can be expressed in the form $3^a7^b$, where $a$ and $b$ are non-negative integers.
I found the following problem in Austrian Mathematical Olympiad: 2016 - Final Round - Q4:
"Demonstrate that any whole number concluding with the digits $133$ must include a prime divisor exceeding $7$."
So far, I have tried to do a proof by contradiction by assuming $n=3^x 7^y$
I would appreciate it if someone could walk me through the solution or point out the correct approach.

What have you tried so far?

Please check out our guide for new askers and fix the post.

@JyrkiLahtonen I am sorry about that. This is all the information I could provide. If I had any context of what exam is this from, I would be more than willing to share it. Unfortunately all I have is the question.

@Ruchin the "trick" here (which seems to have been missed so far) is that if $n$ ends in $133$, it also ends in $33$. Do you need more of a hint or can you take it from there?

@RobinStevenson Could you please clarify the source of the problem? The problem doesn't seem to be in the mentioned olympiad.

@BlueNight My bad. It is Austrian, not Australian. Thank you for mentioning.

@RobinStevenson Thank you! Now I found it, but it was in 2015, not 2016. In case you find this useful, here are past problems with solutions from that competition.

The remaining other possibility is that the number, call it $n$, has the form $3^a7^b$.
If we know the three last digits of a natural number, we also know its residue class modulo $8$. As $133\equiv5\pmod8$, it follows easily that both $a$ and $b$ must be odd ($3^2\equiv7^2\equiv1\pmod8$ and $5\equiv3\cdot7\pmod 8$). So we must have
$$n=21\cdot9^k\cdot 49^\ell$$
with $a=2k+1, b=2\ell+1$.
But this means that the last digit of $n$ would be either $1$ or $9$.

Endorsing Chris Lewis's solution. Posting this to describe a labor saving mechanism taking advantage of the known third digit. I have no idea what the hint about the totient function means

This is a much better method than I used! I'll leave my answer up as an alternative but yours may well explain why the question was "show that no $3^a 7^b$ ends in $133$" rather than "show that no $3^a 7^b$ ends in $33$". I also don't really know what the "hint" about the totient function might have been referring to.

Thank you so much for your time. This is a great solution.

@Chris It can be done even more simply, e.g. see my answer.

@Jyrki Could you please show in your answer the details of "it follows easily that ...". It is not clear exactly which method you intend to use,

very clever indeed! +1

@Mike Disproving congruences via modular checks is bread-and-butter basic number theory - rarely is anything "clever" needed, e.g. to disprove the congruence $,3^a 7^b \equiv 133\pmod{!10^3}$ it suffces to disprove it mod some (small) factor of $10^3.,$ Jyrki chose factors $,8,10,$ but it is simpler to use $,5,4,$ as in my answer. $\ \ $

@BillDubuque "If we know the three last digits of a natural number, we also know its residue class modulo 8."...How ?

@Sophie The last $3$ digits of $,n,$  give its remainder $,r,$ modulo $ 10^3,,$ i.e. $,n = r + 10^3 q = r + \color{#c00}8(125q),,$ so $,n\equiv r\pmod{!\color{#c00}8},$ follows from $,n\equiv r\pmod{!\color{#c00}8\cdot 125},,$ see congruences persist mod $\rm\color{#c00}{factors}$ of the modulus. $\ \ $

@BillDubuque No idea, I got a mystery downvote as well. May be somebody feels that the question is sub-par, and we should know better than to answer it? Shrug.

Not much case analysis is actually necessary here.
Say $n$ ends in $133$. It certainly isn't divisible by $2$ or $5$; so we need to show it can't be of the form $3^a 7^b$.
You can do this by looking at powers of $3$ and $7$ modulo $1000$ and checking if any of their products end in $133$. But as has been pointed out, this leads to a lot of calculations.
The trick here is that if $n$ ends in $133$, it also ends in $33$.
Powers of $7$ modulo $100$ cycle through the values $7$, $49$,$43$,$1$. These of course also list their own inverses; for instance, if $43a \equiv b$ then $a\equiv 7b$.
You only have to check that none of $\{1,7,43,49\}\cdot 33\equiv \{33,31,19,17\}$ is a power of $3$ modulo $100$.

You have a stronger result here! $n\equiv 33\bmod 100$ implies it has a prime factor greater than $7$. Nice.

Thank you so much. This solution is really clever. I would have never think about considering 33 instead of 133 would work. Even though Jyrki had the most elegent solution, yours is the cleverest.

Actually, you can even do it mod 20.  The powers of 3 mod 20 cycle through $3, 9, 7, 1$ and the powers of 7 mod 20 cycle through $7, 9, 3, 1$.  No product of those is congruent to 13 mod 20.

@MichaelLugo That could be the most illuminating answer.

A number with no prime factors greater than $7$ must have only prime factors in $\{2,3,5,7\}$. Such a number takes the form $2^a3^b5^c7^d$. If $n\equiv 133\bmod 1000$ takes this form, it must have no $2$s or $5$s as $133$ is not a multiple of $2$ or $5$. We just need to show that $133$ is not congruent to $3^b7^d$ mod $1000$. This is now a brute force search. We only need to check for $0\le b,d< \phi(1000)=400$.
At this point I used Python. However, as Jyrki points out in the comments, doing it by hand you won't actually have to brute force search the entire $400\times 400$ sized search space. One should check first the order of $3,7$ modulo $1000$, and check for relations of the form $3^k7^l\equiv 1 \bmod 1000$, giving a smaller $200$ sized search space. Still a bit much in my opinion by hand.

$$\lambda(1000)=100$$

You can further reduce the search space: e.g., if $k$ is a multiple of $4$, then both $l=0,1$ don’t work, etc.

You can also reduce the search space by looking at final digits. But it's much quicker to look at the final two digits.

@Pranay No need to search at all: just examine it mod $5$ and $4$, e.g. see my answer. $\ \ $

Proof$_{\:\!1}$ $\!\bmod 20\!:\, 7\equiv 3^{-1}$ so $\,3^a7^b\!\equiv 3^{a-b}\!\in S\equiv \{1,3,9,7\}\,$ but $\,133\!\equiv\! 13\not\in S$ $\,\ \bf\small QED$

Proof$_{\:\!2}$ $ \bmod 4\!:\, \ \ \ \color{#c00}1\equiv 133\ \equiv\,\ 3^{\large a} \color{0af}7^{\large b}\ \equiv \color{#c00}{(-1)^{\color{0af}{\large a+b}}} \Rightarrow\,a\!+\!b\,\ \rm\color{#0a0}{even}$
$\qquad\quad\ \bmod 5\!:\, \color{#c00}{{-}1}\equiv 133^2\!\equiv  3^{\large 2a}7^{\large 2b^{\phantom{|^.}}}\!\!\!\equiv \color{#c00}{(-1)^{\large \color{0af}{a+b}}}\Rightarrow\, a\!+\!b\,\ \rm\color{#0af}{odd},\,$ contra above.  $\, \ \small\bf QED$

Update $ $ In reply to comments (& the $5$ downvotes!) I expand on the (fundamental) method used. If $\:3^a7^b\equiv 133\pmod{\!10^3}\,$ has a solution $\,a,b\in\Bbb N\,$ then it remains a solution $\!\bmod n\,$ for every factor $\,n\,$ of $\,10^3.\,$ We start by testing the smallest factors: $\,2,4,5\ldots\ $  First $\!\bmod 2\,$ it's always true $\,1^a 1^b\equiv 1.\,$ Next,  $\bmod 4,\,$ we get $\,\color{#c00}{(-1)^{a+b}\equiv 1},\,$ thus $\,a\!+\!b\,$ is $\rm\color{#0a0}{even}.\,$ Next $\!\bmod 5\,$ it's $\,3^a 2^b\!\equiv 3;\,$ squaring, by $\,3^2,2^2\equiv -1\,$ we get $\,\color{#c00}{(-1)^{a+b}\equiv -1},\: $ so $\ a\!+\!b\,$ is $\rm\color{#0af}{odd},\,$ contra, above. [The first proof is an optimization - we further require that the two  generators $\:\!7,3\:\!$  collapse to one via $\,7^k\equiv 3.\,$ Quickly we find a small  value $\,k=-1\,$ that works, where $\,7^{-1}\equiv 3\!\iff\! 1\equiv 21\!\iff\! 20\equiv 0$].
Summarizing: no solution exists $\!\bmod 10^3$ since assuming so leads to a $\rm\color{#0a0}{parity}$ $\rm\color{#0af}{contradiction}$ when reducing the purported solution $\!\bmod 4\,$ and $\!\bmod 5.\,$ Such modular reduction obstructions are one of the simplest and most widely used methods to prove Diophantine equations unsolvable.

@Downvoter If anything is not clear you are welcome to ask questions. It's all trivial mod arithmetic.

I did not downvote this--I do tell why when I do downvote an answer as I appreciate the courtesy myself!--but with that said, this answer here is quite sparse and I am finding this hard-to-follow, especially in light of the above answers.

@Mike Where are you stuck? This is simpler than all the other answers. $\ \ $

Well, to be honest I didn't go through much effort of mentally compiling this . The reason being is that with the earlier answers above I hardly even had to. It's more sparsely written here but I'm not sure it is simpler. In general, it seems that  later answers tend to get judged more harshly on here I think. I do think more words on this post would help.

In particular, what was meant by the $()^2$ above the $\implies$?

@Miike That square operation means: square the prior congruence (using  $,3^2\equiv -1\equiv 7^2).,$ It is essential to grok modular arithmetic  if you wish to master number theory.

This is super elegant, well done. I'm in two minds about the style - I initially found it a little off-putting but actually following it through is quite satisfying (the fact you have to do a little work reading it feels a bit like solving it yourself!). I'm not sure it would be the most suitable style if this had been the only answer but among all the others I think it's great.

IMHO, this answer is a bit obtuse, or at least too sparse. I think you should explicitly state that in mod 4 a+b must be even for the congruence to hold, but in mod 5 we need a+b to be odd, hence there's a contradiction.

I see it now, @BillDubuque . Very elegant indeed but I do find it much clearer now after the edits +1

My point is that I don't feel that your notation is self-explanatory. However, I was viewing your answer using my phone's forced-dark mode, and some of your text was invisible, making it appear even terser. ;) (The text 'a+b' before 'odd' and 'even' was invisible).

@PM2Ring $ $ Kudos - you correctly guessed the $TeX$nicolor parity contradiction hidden by dark mode! $\ \ \ $  I appended an update to the $2$-line proof. Now it should be more widely accessible.

What a clever solution. Thank you so much for your time.

Just to add some details to the nice answers already posted, the subgroup of $(\mathbb{Z}/1000)^{\times}$ generated by $3$ and $7$ has order 200, so it is of index $2$  ( since $|(\mathbb{Z}/1000)^{\times}|=\phi(1000)=400$).  One could see this by noticing first that $3^{100}=7^{20}=3^{10}7^{18}= 1 \mod 1000$. So there exists a real  Dirichlet character $\mod 1000$ $\mu$( that is, with values $\pm 1$) such that $\mu(3)=\mu(7) = 1$, but $\mu(133) = -1$. In Mathematica's notation, it will be the Dirichlet character with index $251$, as one can check, see also WA.
$\bf{Added:}$
Let's write explicitly a Dirichlet character $\mod 1000$ that is $1$ on $3$ and $7$, but $-1$ on $133$.   From theory we know that a Dirichlet character $\mod 1000$ is the product of a Dirichlet character $\mod 8$ and a Dirichlet character $\mod 125$.  This also works for real Dirichlet characters ( i. e. those with values $\pm 1$). Now, a Dirichlet character $\mod 8$ is a multiplicative function from $(\mathbb{Z}/8)^{\times} \to \{\pm 1\}$.  Here is one that takes values $-1$ on $3$, $7$, but $1$ on $133=5 \mod 8$, it comes from
$$(\mathbb{Z}/8)^{\times}\to (\mathbb{Z}/4)^{\times}\simeq \{\pm 1\}$$
Now for the character $\mod 125$, it is
$$\mathbb(\mathbb{Z}/125)^{\times}\to  (\mathbb{Z/5})^{\times} \to \{ \pm 1\}$$
where the last one is the Legendre character ( takes $3$, $7$, and $133 = 3\mod 5$ to $-1$ )
Now take the product of the above two Dirichlet characters. It takes $3$ and $7$ to $1$, but $133$ to $-1$.

Note that the question is tagged elementary-number-theory so it is highly unlikely that the OP knows anything about Dirichlet characters (and likely the same for group theory). As such, you might consider rephrasing it in more accessible terms.

Of course, but the point of my comment was to nudge you to elaborate so that many  more readers might find it useful.

@Bill Dubuque:  did add more details, will think some more about it

If we look at the group generated by 3 modulo 100.
3,9,27,81,43,29, etc.
There are 20 members to this group.  Every element has an even number in the 10s digit. 7 is a member of the group.
All numbers that can be expressed as $3^i7^j$ have an even number in the 10's digit.

Simpler $!\bmod 20!:\ 3^a \in S\equiv {1,3,9,7},$ so $,7\equiv 3^3\Rightarrow ,3^a 7^b\in S,,$ but $,133\equiv 13\not\in S\ \ $

@BillDubuque Yes that is simpler.
